# KVM: VNC connection blocked

Tags: kvm-virtualization, vnc

I'm running a KVM host with three client vms. Two ubuntu servers and one windows server r2 2008.

All three VMs have the VNC option enabled in their XML config file:

```
<graphics type='vnc' port='5910' autoport='no' listen='0.0.0.0' keymap='de'>
  <listen type='address' address='0.0.0.0'/>
</graphics>

<graphics type='vnc' port='5911' autoport='no' listen='0.0.0.0' keymap='de'>
  <listen type='address' address='0.0.0.0'/>
</graphics>

<graphics type='vnc' port='5912' autoport='no' listen='0.0.0.0' keymap='de'>
  <listen type='address' address='0.0.0.0'/>
</graphics>
```

And the given ports are opened on start:

```
user@kvm-host:~$ netstat -tpln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1061/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 192.168.100.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2811/dnsmasq
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5269            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1844/beam
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5910            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4497/qemu-system-x8
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:40758           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1844/beam
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1680/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5911            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4532/qemu-system-x8
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5912            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2844/qemu-system-x8
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5280            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1844/beam
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5281            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1844/beam
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:38724           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1131/rpc.statd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5222            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1844/beam
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      1061/rpcbind
tcp6       0      0 :::4369                 :::*                    LISTEN      1753/epmd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1680/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::52896                :::*                    LISTEN      1131/rpc.statd
```

And i have added an rule to iptables:

```
sudo iptables -L
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:5911
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:5910
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:5912
```

But i'm not able to connect via vnc from remote! I'm able to connect on localhost via telnet to port 5910. 
The local telnet connection returns RFB 003.008. But when connecting from external the connection runs out of time.

What can i do?

Comment: Does [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/262700/qemu-kvm-vnc-support) help?

Comment: Check your firewall.

Comment: @garethTheRed: no, doesn't work.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I already checked my firewall. Already mentionted in my post!